# How to reverse XML data tags using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, reverse

For example, below XML file.

```
<person>
<name>Adam</name>
<lname>Palmer</lname>
<profession> Programmer</profession>
<salary>80,000</salary>
</person>
```

Now, In XSLT, IF I code,

```
<xsl:template match="person">
 <xsl:apply-templates/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

So, In HTML file It will display: Adam Palmer Programmer 80,000.

But I need following output: **Palmer Adam Programmer 80,000.**

I need to reverse order of first 2 data tags.

Any idea folks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push style stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="person/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:text>&#x20;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="person">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="lname"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::name|self::lname)]"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
Palmer Adam  Programmer 80,000
```

Answer (score 1):

You could easily handle tag per tag.

But if the logic is right for anything but the name and firstname, I would isolate them.

like this :

```
<person>
<name>
  <fname>Adam</fname>
  <lname>Palmer</lname>
</name>
<profession> Programmer</profession>
<salary>80,000</salary>
</person>
```

that way you can add a seperate template for the `<name>` tag.

Of course, often the structure of the xml is not alterable than you can do :

```
<xsl:template match="person">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="lname"/></xsl:text>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/></xsl:text>
 < -- rest of the tags --> 
</xsl:template>


<xs:template match="lname>
   <xsl:value-of "." />
</xsl:template>    


<xs:template match="name>
   <xsl:value-of "." />
</xsl:template>
```

and so on..

That way might lead to some more boilerplate like code, but you gain flexibility (when tags need seperate logic)

NOTE : this might not be copy paste material, just typed it in without the possibility to test, the logics remain though.